# How to get number of HTML elements in JavaScript and put it to string

Tags: javascript, count, element, nightwatch.js

HTLM source:

`<ul id="dropdownSelectRole" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
   <li><a href="#"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">aaaa</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">abcd</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">admin</a></li>
</ul>`

JS code:

```
'should verify counter on active tab': function (browser) {
    //Given
    var welcome = browser.page.welcome();
    var users = browser.page.users();
    //When
    welcome.click('@usersButton');
    var count = users.size.element('@table');
    //Then
    users.expect.element('@activeTab').contains.text(count);
},
```

My code doesn't work cause still getting errors like TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined  or   TypeError: undefined is not a function.

What i need is to take the number of elements from the HTML table and put it to some string in order to assert later on with value on a tab.
Simple test that number displayed in a tab is relevant to number of records.

I am using page object (users and welcome are pseudo-classes with listed elements selectors, @table is selector of the table with elements, @activeTab is selector of the tab which contain number of records).

To make question simply I need in JS something like this JAVA:

`int count = getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//*@id=\"content\"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr")).size();
        String count1 = Integer.toString(count);`

Comment: where is the java part?

Comment: I'd take JQuery to count objects like $(object).each(function(){ var i++});

Comment: @Micromonger you mean simply `$(object).length` to count them but this isn't a jQuery question

Comment: @Micromonger could you pls give me ready solution ? I am newbie ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery, you may use size(), or length (if version greater than 1.8)

```
$(object).size(); //$(object).length
```

Or use something like this

```
var count = 0;
for(var i in object) {
    count++;
}
//If you need count only attributes (not functions)
var count = 0;
for(var i in object) {
    if(object.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Second part of code is pure js, you can use it without jQuery

Comment: `.length` is the plain javascript method to count array elements. If you select some elements with jQuery, it returns -compare to plain javascript it returns not an array if the size of result is zero or one- always an array. So it doesn't need Jquery 1.8+